How to prevent mouse to go beyond screen borders / getting into dead zone in multi-monitor setup?
I've been facing an issue on Linux Mint (Cinnamon) on my multi-monitor (3 monitors) setup because my mouse annoyingly gets into a dead zone going beyond screen borders when all monitors do not have the same orientation, as for one of my monitors is vertically oriented.
This is detrimental for my daily usage as it's something that does not allow me to use maximize snapping on Linux, neither half snapping when taking a window up to the bottom.
I also make use of Windows (OS) and this does not happen at all.
Alignment of upper and lower borders of all screens is not an option as they're physically set up (wall mounted) as seen on the attached screenshot.

How may I overcome this issue without getting into unreasonably using non-sense alchemy-wise scripts and obscure settings?
Thanks in advance
